# Building multiple assembly project with CoreCLR and dnu

Tags: dnx, coreclr, dnu

What's the best practice for building a CoreCLR/DNX project comprised of multiple assemblies?

Would there be a project.json for each assembly and would each need to be manually built using a custom script or can the existing build tools walk these dependencies and build everything itself?

Are there any examples of projects like this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, each assembly == a NuGet package == a project.json.

A good example of a solution with multiple assemblies is [Mvc](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/dev/src).

The ASP.NET team uses [KoreBuild](https://github.com/aspnet/korebuild), an internal (but public) too to orchestrate the build. The idea is that it calls `dotnet/dnu` build/pack/publish on the projects. KoreBuild looks for projects under `src`, `test`, and `samples`.

Both with `dnu` and `dotnet` it's easy to build an entire project graph:

- `dnu` supports globbing patterns so you can do somethig like `dnu build src/**` and it will figure out the graph in that folder.
- `dotnet` already knows what was compiled before so you don't need to care. Just call `dotnet build` on each project and it will rebuild it's dependencies if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Victor.  I've since discovered I can just create a package.json in each project and so long as I include a dependency section on the other assembly the build tool seems to sort it out. ie: in one project.json in the dependencies section I just include `"MyOtherAssembly": "*"`